# How to replace a list elements that specify some constraint?

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, polynomials

Let's say I have the list :

```
-5 u[x, y, z] + 6 v[x, y, z]
```

and want to get as a result -u[x,y,z] + v[x,y,z].
I have tried :

```
{-5 u[x, y, z] + 6 v[x, y, z]} /. j_Integer?NonNegative*expr : _ :> expr
(* -5u[x,y,z] + v[x,y,z]*)
```

Is there any way to have just 1 or -1 as coefficient in a final polynomial ?

Comment: `/. i_Integer :> Sign[i]`?

Comment: `-5 u[x, y, z] + 6 v[x, y, z] /. x_?NumberQ :> Sign[x]`

Comment: Works.
Thank you.

Comment: -5 u[x, y, z] + 6 v[x, y, z] /. x_?NumericQ -> Sign[x]

Answer (score 1):

Another approach can be something like this:

```
coeffList = 
  CoefficientList[-5 u[x, y, z] + 6 v[x, y, z], {u[x, y, z], 
    v[x, y, z]}];

Plus @@ ((Sign /@ coeffList).{u[x, y, z], v[x, y, z]})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3]
f1 = MapAt[Sign, #, {All, 1}]&;

f2 = # /. (# -> Sign@# & /@ Coefficient[#, Variables@#]) &;

f3 = Dot[Variables@#, Sign@Coefficient[#, Variables@#]] &;

f1[-5 u[x, y, z] + 6 v[x, y, z]]
```

> -u[x, y, z] + v[x, y, z]

```
Equal @@ (#[-5 u[x, y, z] + 6 v[x, y, z]] & /@ {f1, f2, f3})
```

> True